# camera.render reads a file in the middle of a gameplay

Tags: unity

Why does `camera.render` read a file in the middle of a gameplay? This causes a lag in my game:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's loading something based on culling results. Could be related to level of detail changes, or deferring material setup until an object using the material is in view. Can you isolate what object in your scene causes the file load when it comes into view?

Comment: So you are saying disable AutoLOD?

Comment: I said no such words. I suggested experimenting in your scene so we can narrow down which objects cause this. There may be a way to force those objects to fully pre-load in  advance so you don't encounter a spike mid-play.